# Java socket HTTPClient: using two inputstreams

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I'm a newbie in Java and I'm writing a HTTP Client which retrieves HTML content from an URL and writes this response to a file. After that, all the images of the requested webpage should also be stored locally.

I've written a function that creates a new request, a function to retrieve a HTML-file and a function to retrieve the images. Unfortunately, I'm unable to retrieve the images; they are not written and stored in the location.

I guess the problem is that i'm using two different Inputstreams. How should I rewrite my code to solve this? I'm not allowed to use the OpenStream() function from my instructor: it has to happen with a manual GET-request.

Thanks in advance.

```
private static String createRequest(URL url, String httpCmd,
        boolean version1_1) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(httpCmd.toUpperCase());
    sb.append(' ');
    String path = url.getPath();
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
        path = "/" + path;
    }
    sb.append(path);
    if (version1_1) {
        sb.append(" HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        sb.append("Host: ");
        sb.append(url.getHost());
        sb.append("\r\n");
    } else {
        sb.append(" HTTP/1.0\r\n");
    }
    sb.append("\r\n");
    return sb.toString();
}





public void retrieveFile(String htppCommand, String url, int port,
        String htppversion) throws IOException {

    Socket s = new Socket();

    URL u;
    if (url.startsWith("http://")) {
        u = new URL(url);
    } else {
        u = new URL("http://" + url);
    }

    try {
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(u.getHost(), port));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("../output.html");

        byte[] data = new byte[4096];

        pw.print(createRequest(u, htppCommand, true));
        pw.flush();


        int length;
        int imagenumber = 0;

        while ((length = in.read(data)) != -1) {

            System.out.println(new String(data));
            out.write(data, 0, length);

            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new String(data));
            Elements images = doc
                    .select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");

            for (Element image : images) {

                imagenumber++;
                retrieveImage(image.attr("src"), s, imagenumber);

            }

        }

        pw.close();
        in.close();
        out.close();

    }
    // Host not found
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        if (s != null)
            s.close();
        System.err.println("Host not found: " + url);
        System.exit(1);
        return;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // close the socket
    s.close();

}



public void retrieveImage(String imageurl, Socket s, int imagenumber)
        throws IOException {

    String extension = "";

    // System.out.println(image);
    if (imageurl.contains(".jpg")) {
        extension = ".jpg";

    } else {

        if (imageurl.contains(".png")) {

            extension = ".png";

        }

        else {
            extension = ".gif";

        }
    }

    String path = "../image" + imagenumber + extension;

    URL myurl = new URL(imageurl);

    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path);
    printer.print(createRequest(myurl, "GET", true));
    printer.flush();

    int length = 0;

    byte[] b = new byte[4096];

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {

        os.write(b, 0, length);

    }

    is.close();
    os.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that you're trying to reuse the socket from the fist request. In classic request-response you're supposed to close the socket after you you retrieved the response and create a new socket for another request. You probably don't want to mess with the Keep-Alive connections just for the homework. For the sake of simplicity each of your HTTP requests should open a new socket and hence have it's own InputStream. Also, there should be no difference between how request are made between the html page itself and the images.

So for each request:

- Open new socket with host/port
- Open input stream and write the request in it
- Retrieve the response via the socket's output stream
- Close input and output streams
- Close the socket connection

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why so hard? Use Apache HttpClient.

Comment: @Michael-O it's his assignment to implement the http client.